# Run SQL execute immediate query to merge tables in Bigquery inside python function

Tags: google-bigquery

Hopefully you can help me understand, I'm trying to run an execute immediate query that I've constructed in Python which is quite complex. So, that i can easy change parameters each time. But Python is complaining

```
BadRequest: 400 Query error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element at [1:19]
```

Could you help me identify what is happening?

The query helps me run a pivot table in the 2nd dataframe, based on ID from the 1st dataframe

```py
        def aggre_secondary_data(dataset, table, table2, uniqid, date_column, brand_column, 
                                                                       var_agg=[], agg= "sum",  

        date_format='%m'):
        table_name = 'project.'+ dataset + '.' + table
        table_name_2 = 'project.'+ dataset + '.' + table2
            
        query0 = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT " + uniqid + " , " + brand_column + " || '_' || as 
         brand_month, " +", ".join(var_agg)
        query1 = " FROM `%s`"%(table_name_2) + "\n" + "WHERE " + uniqid + " IN (SELECT DISTINCT 
        CAST(" + uniqid + " as STRING) as " +  uniqid + "\n"
        query2 = "FROM `%s`"%(table_name) + "as reduced_df) " + "\n" + ")" 
        
        query3 = query0 + query1 + query2 
        
        pivot_f = "\n"+ "PIVOT "
        
        temp =''
        for i in var_agg:
            temp = temp + (" " + agg + "(" + i + ") " + i )
            pivot = "(" + temp + " FOR brand_month IN (" + """'"""  +'''"""''' +  " ||  
              string_agg(brand_month,"
            pivot2 = pivot +  ''' "','" '''  +  " )" + """ || """ +  '''"""''' + "'"      + "))" 
           +"\n"+ " ORDER BY " + uniqid
        
        query_brand_month = "SELECT " + brand_column + " || '_' || Month brand_month"
        query_date = "SELECT DISTINCT Month FROM `%s`"%(table_name_2)
        query_brands = "SELECT DISTINCT " + brand_column +  " FROM `%s`"%(table_name_2)
           
        final_query = """SELECT '''"""  + query3 + pivot_f+ pivot2 + '\n' + """ ''' """ +"\n"+ 
        "FROM (" +"\n"+ query_brand_month + "\n"+ " FROM (" + query_brands +")" +"\n"+ "CROSS JOIN 
        (" 
        + query_date +" ) " +"\n"+ "ORDER BY brand_month )"
            
        return final_query
    
    def execute_query(dataset,table,table2):
        client = bigquery.Client()
        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)
        
        temp = 'execute immediate ('
        main_query = aggre_secondary_data("blue_test","data1","test", uniqid = "ID", date_column = "Month" , 
                         brand_column ="PRODUCT_" , var_agg=["P","R"], agg= "sum", date_format='%m')
        sql= temp + main_query + ")"
        query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
        df = query_job.result().to_dataframe()
        return df
    
    execute_query(dataset="blue_test",table="data1",table2="test")
```

I know that if I'm running the query in python I would do:

```py
    query_4 = f"""\
    #standardsql      
    execute immediate ( 
    
    SELECT .......
    '
    )
    """
    df_final = bqclient.query(query).result().to_dataframe()
```

this is the resulting final_query that gets printed:

```sql
    SELECT '''SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID , PRODUCT || '_' || EXTRACT(month FROM PARSE_DATETIME( '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', Date )) Month brand_month, P, R FROM `project.test_string_date`
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(ID as INT) as ID
FROM `project.blue_test.data1`as reduced_df) 
)
PIVOT ( sum(P) P, sum(R) R FOR brand_month IN ("''' ||  string_agg(brand_month, '","' ) || '''"))
 ORDER BY ID
 ''' 
FROM (
SELECT PRODUCT || '_' || Month brand_month
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT FROM `project.blue_test.test_string_date`)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(month FROM PARSE_DATETIME( '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', Date )) as Month FROM `project.blue_test.test_string_date` ) 
ORDER BY brand_month )
```

and that results in this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID , PRODUCT || '_' || EXTRACT(month FROM PARSE_DATETIME( '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', Date )) as Month, brand_month, P, R FROM `project.test_string_date`
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(ID as INT) as ID
FROM `project.blue_test.data1`as reduced_df) 
)
PIVOT ( sum(P) P, sum(R) R FOR brand_month IN ("a_1","a_10","a_2","a_3","a_4","a_5","a_6","a_7","a_8","a_9","b_1","b_10","b_2","b_3","b_4","b_5","b_6","b_7","b_8","b_9","c_1","c_10","c_2","c_3","c_4","c_5","c_6","c_7","c_8","c_9","d_1","d_10","d_2","d_3","d_4","d_5","d_6","d_7","d_8","d_9"))
 ORDER BY ID
```

It complains that brand month shouldn't be there. I dont understand why

this is the error that is showing:

```
Unrecognized name: brand_month at [1:117]
```

This is the format of my 2nd table

ID Date      PRODUCT    P   R

1234    01/05/2020 00:00    a   34  12

1233    01/03/2020 00:00    b   54  0

Comment: show resulting text of `final_query`

Comment: I've added the resulting text of final_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is the resulting final_query that gets printed:

```
SELECT '''SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID , PRODUCT || '_' || EXTRACT(month FROM PARSE_DATETIME( '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', Date )) Month brand_month, P, R FROM `project.blue_test.test_string_date`    
...    
...
```

> It complains that brand month shouldn't be there. I dont understand why

You should remove `Month` right before `brand_month`, so the first line should look as

```
SELECT '''SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID , PRODUCT || '_' || EXTRACT(month FROM PARSE_DATETIME( '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', Date )) brand_month, P, R FROM `project.blue_test.test_string_date`    
...    
...
```

Comment: consider also voting up the answer if it helped

Comment: thank you! I had just find the issue when I saw this, it took me days